# Shift bits of an integer only if the number of bits of its binary presentation is greater then given value

Tags: c#

I need to shift the bits of an integer to the right only if the number of bits is greater then a certain number. For the example Lets take 10.

If the integer is 818 the then binary representation of the integer is `1100110010`, In that case i do nothing.
If the Integer is 1842 the binary representation of the integer is `11100110010` which is greater then 10 by one, So i need to shift one bit to the right(Or setting bit at index 10 to 0 which gives the same result as far as i know, Maybe im wrong).
What i did until now is make an integer array of ones and zeros represent the int, But i`m sure there is more elegant way of doing this

```
    int y = 818;
    string s = Convert.ToString(y, 2);
    int[] bits = s.PadLeft(8, '0') 
             .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())) 
             .ToArray();
    if (bits.Length > 10)
    {
        for (int i = 10; i < bits.Length; i++)
        {
            bits[i] = 0;
        }
}
```

I also tried to do this:

`if(bits.Length > 10){ y = y >> (bits.Length - 10)}`

but for some reason i got 945 (`1110110001`) when the input was 1891 (`11101100011`)

Comment: The AND number with bit 10 = 0 : number = number & 0xFFFFFDFF;

Comment: @ATT: You appear to be clearing all high bits, not doing any shifting.  Are you sure you don't want simply (`y &= 0x3FF`) ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do this with strings. 2 to the power of 10 has 11 binary digits, so

```
if (y >= Math.Pow(2, 10))
{
    y = y >> 1;
}
```

seems to do what you want.

Comment: Can further simplify that condition to `if (y >= (1 << 10))`

Comment: No need to recalculate every time - `if (y >= 1024)` should be enough.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser: The compiler ought to do the calculation of `(1 << 10)` in advance and generate the exact same code from YellowAfterlife's comment as for `(y >= 1024)`.  iabobski's version involves conversion between integer and double and I'm less sure it gets precomputed.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're correct; I was more referring to the `Math.Pow(2, 10)` part. Sorry for not expressing that more clearly.

Comment: Not sure why I've been downvoted. I agree it can be simplified, but the questioner made it clear that 10 was an example not a fixed number, so I was showing one way that the condition could be calculated at the time. @YellowAfterlife 's suggestion is an improvement.